# Что та проще либо как то иначе

Tags: javascript

```
(input = eCr('input', {type:'file', accept:(vl[1] == 1 ? 'video' : 'image')+'/*'})).click()

input.onchange = e => {
```

Сперва создаю объект, затем кликаю по нему из js, затем вешаю событие которое срабатывает после выбора фала

Вопрос в том, возможно ли делать это проще, скажем не кликая по нему, что бы сразу открывалось окно выбора файла.

Comment: Скажем сразу открыть окно выбора файла, не создавать элемент, не кликать по нему из js. Просто открыть, сразу окно с указанными параметрами.

Comment: нет, такого сделать нельзя, так как браузер просто не предоставляет соответствующих интерфейсов.